# How does a liquid state in Earth's inner/outer core allow a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

I'm pretty sure metal loses more of its structure as it heats up and magnetic properties in a material are caused by a particular combination of atomic arrangement and orbital levels so...how does the difference in rotation of Earth's liquid inner and outer core generate any kind of magnetic field? Why wouldn't Earth's magnetic field be even stronger if those two layers were completely stationary and solid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Earth even have a magnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373449/)

Comment: Also [Is Earth really a magnet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/215747/)